# + Sign With Number Regex

Tags: regex

I want to check if the string has + sign in the beginning and the string is numeric with not more then 15 integers. Also the string shouldn't have any special characters or - in between the integers.

I'm using this regex: `/\+?(?:(?:63)|0)*[.-]?9[0-9]{2}[.]?[0-9]{3}[.]?[0-9]{3,4}/Ui`

But it shows error if the string doesn't have `9` after + sign. e.g. if I use `+891234567` then it shows error.

Please help

Comment: What does "it shows error" mean?

Comment: can you please explain what you're *really* trying to match for.. your stated description is nothing like that regex..so either your regex is way off or else you aren't fully explaining the whole context

Comment: based on your description, this is what you can use: `/^\+?\d{1,15}$/` this matches for a number that is between 1 and 15 digits (inclusive) with an optional `+` prefix.  But this is way different than your posted regex...

Comment: By error it shows, I mean it doesn't passes the number to db even if the number is valid and integer. By valid, I mean it contains + sign at the begining of string

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: Thanks Crayon, it works. Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A "start with `+` followed by 1 to 15 digits" expression would be

```
^\+[[:digit:]]{1,15}
```

This is obviously not what you want but it's not clear from the question what you are hoping to do besides the above.  Please use this to explain better what you actually want.

Comment: Thank you Floris, Crayon's suggested code works perfectly. +1 for you too

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are looking for the following regex should help...

```
^\+\d{1,15}
```

Good Luck!